# macOS Catalina blueoothd high CPU IOBluetoothBroadcomSchedulerWorkaround issue

Tags: macos, bluetooth, catalina

I've already spent many hours with this and I wasn't able to come up with a solution. Since 10.14.x (I don't remember exactly, currently on 10.15.2) I am have been having this issue (and console flooded with the following message and bluetoothd causes CPU usage of 40-120 %, too) :

```
bluetoothd     EVENT:  ModeChange
bluetoothd  == IOBluetoothBroadcomSchedulerWorkaround start
bluetoothd  USBProductID 0x7B   USBVendorID 0x5AC
bluetoothd  schedularWorkaroundActive? 0
bluetoothd  active? 0
bluetoothd  == IOBluetoothBroadcomSchedulerWorkaround end
bluetoothd     EVENT:  ModeChange
bluetoothd  Apple HID device count: 0
bluetoothd  updateAppleHIDConnectionIntervals - connectedAppleDevices 0
bluetoothd  updateAppleHIDConnectionIntervals - twoSniffAttemptDeviceCount 0
bluetoothd  updateAppleHIDConnectionIntervals - connectedSCODeviceCount 0
bluetoothd  Dont enable MSS for this device Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Mouse
bluetoothd  == IOBluetoothBroadcomSchedulerWorkaround end
```

Happens with a Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Mouse and two different (Logitech) mouses, too. Any ideas what I could try? I've already tried deleting plists, NVRAM, reseting SMC, booting into Safe Mode, reseting BT setting in macOS… Thanks!

More details: Machine specs are: MBP 13" 2018 (2.3/16/512). 
Apart from this, bluetooth connection drops randomly and the issue occurs both with Wi-Fi on and off and the USB-C dock connnected and disconnected.

Comment: It also happens to me with ThinkPad BT Keyboard (with TrackPoint, aka a mouse), on either of my Mac. It does not happen when I disconnect the TP keyboard and using Logitech K480 (pure keyboard).  (mac1: 2016 12", freshly-installed Catalina;; mac2: 2019 13"Pro, Catalina upgraded from Mojave)

Comment: Apple is still investigating the issue and they haven't come up with anything yet.. :|

Comment: @amdyes I don't know whether you are notified if a question is aswered. This settings seems to fix it. Use the Bluetooth Explorer from XCode Dev tools to set it this way (see the answer).

Comment: Thanks for the notification. Well I have downgraded, and will keep using Mojave until 10.15.6 released to avoid other minor bugs.

Comment: The issue PERSISTS in macOS 11.0.1 :-((

Comment: @amdyes persists in the final release of the Big Sur :-((

Comment: … Persists in 11.2 …

Comment: Hey @tantin, why did you revert my fix of your typo within title? There is `blueoothd` instead of `bluetooth`.

Comment: That’s quite simple to explain - it isn’t a typo as the process which is affected by/causes the bug / is the cause of high CPU usage IS *bluetoothd* - Bluetooth daemon which is responsible for handling whatever has anything in common with the Bluetooth technology.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found a workaround: I've figured out MSS probably means Master-Slave-Switch. That didn't suffice to fix the issue. But disabling sniff mode resolves the issue. It seems that some energy management code doesn't work properly. [image]

The cause of the issue traced down: Apple has a bug within BT3.0 Stack. This issue is not happening with anything BT4.0+.

Comment: How did you bring this window up?

Comment: @gen It's Bluetooth Explorer (part of the XCode companion tools available at Apple website to download). Then there: (menubar) Devices -> Connection list -> select -> Link Policy -> Uncheck. It seems to last only for the current session, if the device goes asleep, you have to repeat this process.

Comment: Thanks for this post, I found the app in the end and it did help bring down the CPU levels! And yes, it only seems to last for the session. Thanks again :)

Comment: Just in case anyone else hits this issue, Bluetooth Explorer doesn't open a window when you run it, it just has a menu bar. See @tantin's comment above

Comment: Could anyone make a cmdline program to disable sniff mode (instead of a GUI macro)? These libs might be useful PureSwift/Bluetooth, PureSwift/BluetoothDarwin.

Comment: Wow, just took my blueetoothd from 40-85% CPU to 0.4! 

Bluetooth Explorer link which nobody had pasted before is: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

You have to click some accepts to sign up for an apple dev account if you had not already, doesn't take a second. Then as mentioned above, search for "additional tools" and grab the latest version available.

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed in 10.15.6 beta 3, and for now, this is my workaround - force killing the process in activity monitor.

"Activity Monitor" into Spotlight -> CPU -> find `bluetoothd` -> Force Quit.

Apart from the obvious CPU usage drop, you can also confirm this worked via the console with `bluetoothd` (no extra params) and see how the log has drastically quieted down.

Comment: Hooray. Finally. Killing bluetoothd wasn't solution for me as this means killing for example bluetooth audio or other thing and it reoccurs again after some time.

Comment: I've updated to 10.5.6 (final release). Unfortunately the issue still persists for me. @Housemd

Comment: 10.15.7 – No fix. Hopefully 11.0 will fix that. :-(

Answer (score 3):

My answer: The only solution (besides the workaround with bluetooth explorer) I have found so far is switching to a bluetooth device which uses BT 4.0 or above.

And here some background findings:

- MS Sculpt Comfort Mouse and other BT 3.x devices are affected by this macOS bug
- MS Surface Mobile Mouse (BT 4.x) and probably other BT 4.x/5.x hardware is not affected
- the problem disappeared on my M1 Mac Mini during Big Sur 11.0 and 11.1, but as soon as Apple "fixed" its Bluetooth issues with 11.2, the problem reappeared.

Comment: Verified with my two ThinkPad Bluetooth Keyboards (gen 1 BT 3.0, gen 2 BT 5.0). The keyboard has a track point on it which works like a mouse.

Comment: My MS Sculpt Comfort Mouse died, so I'll be able to verify that (have bought a BT 5.0 mouse, thx!) tomorrow.

Comment: Verified. No issue with BT 5.0 mouse. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to say that 10.15.6 does not solve the CPU issue (at least for me), though the logs seem to have quietened down.

While we wait for this to be resolved properly, I've actually automated turning off "Sniff Mode" via Bluetooth Explorer using Keyboard Maestro. Download [this file](https://gist.github.com/nickevansuk/7acc43e50c4bfe7c0d97325989258b39) and save it as "Fix Bluetooth Mouse.kmmacros".

When you've installed it into Keyboard Maestro, simply press Control+Shift+1 every time you hear your Mac's fan go into overdrive (which happens when the CPU spikes due to this bug).

Note you'll need to install Bluetooth Explorer first.

Comment: You are not the only one, it still persists for me, too… both the CPU and (a little bit reduced in volumes) the flooded log.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is still facing this issue, I was able to solve this issue on my macOS Mojave 10.14.6 with tips from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1035661/1252519)

It seems that when you upgrade the operating system (maybe also when just installing updates):

> bluetooth settings are backed up and are read by the system

Indeed this seemed to be the case on my system.

#### Symptoms

It is likely that both processes `bluetoothd` and `cfdprefd` are consuming extreme CPU processing power (>>1%). Please confirm before and after trying the solution below.

In my case my fan was always running almost at full power and CPU getting to 100ºC. Now I am writing this with CPU at 50ºC while using a Magic Mouse, Magic Keyboard and a bluetooth headset.

#### Step-by-step solution

1. If possible, turn off bluetooth on the mac and all the bluetooth devices previously connected to this mac (that are in the detection range of the mac)
2. Open a Finder window
3. Hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>
4. Paste `/Library/Preferences/` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
5. Hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and paste `com.apple.Bluetooth`
6. **Carefully** select all the files whose names **start** with `com.apple.Bluetooth` and **contain** `.plist` (likely at the end or before some random characters)
7. Move the files to Trush (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>)
8. Repeat steps 2-7 replacing `/Library/Preferences/` with `~/Library/Preferences/` in step 3
9. Back up all your work, close all apps, and shut down your mac
10. Reset the PRAM, following [the official instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) (Just hold <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> right after pressing the power button and **hold** these keys until the mac restarts twice, i.e. you hear booting sound twice or see the logo twice).
11. After booting up open *Preferences* --> *Bluetooth* and remove all the devices that might still show up in there.
12. Restart the mac
13. After restart try to pair your bluetooth devices again. Things now should just work as expected.
14. Be kind to someone today :)

Comment: I'd tried that once, didn't help. I've tried it one once again. No change for me. Nonetheless, thanks!

Comment: @tantin could you share the symptoms regarding bluetoothd and cfdprefd on your system?

Comment: @tatin try resetting the SMC (search google support website) as well after step 9

Comment: As for symptoms: See the original post…

Comment: @tantin so that means `cfdprefd` is not an issue for you? only the `bluetoothd` consuming a lot of CPU ? Unfortunately I do not remember taking any other steps that could help :(

Comment: Nope, just the bluetoothd...