# Why is the process bluetoothd taking up to 100% of a CPU core

Tags: bluetooth

Over the past few months I've noticed the process bluetoothd taking up to 100% of a CPU core. I normally only have a bluetooth mouse and keyboard connected. With just the mouse and keyboard connected the process periodically (a couple minutes every hour) ramps up from <10% to 100%.
But, when I have a bluetooth mouse, keyboard, and headset connected the bluetoothd process tends to stay 90-100% while the headset is connected.

(side problem) Bluetooth sporadically will take a couple minutes to connection or I will have to turn bluetooth off/on to make the initially connection when I log-on for the day.

- **Computer**: Mid-2012 Macbook 15"
- **OS**: Catalina (happened in last couple major updates too)
- **Keyboard**: Microsoft Mobile Keyboard 6000
- **Mouse**: Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Mouse Bluetooth
- **Headphones**: Jabra Evolve 65

[image]

^This is with Mouse, Keyboard, and Headset connected but without audio playing

## Attempted Fix

I've tried power cycling bluetooth and computer. I've tried resetting the Bluetooth module. I've deleted the .plist.

Any other suggestions? It doesn't make sense that the bluetoothd process use that much resources when it never did a few OS versions ago.

Comment: I have figured out this workaround: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377853/macos-catalina-blueoothd-high-cpu-iobluetoothbroadcomschedulerworkaround-issue?rq=1

Comment: it could be due to the non-apple devices you have.  Just a guess.

Comment: @jmh Nope, it's incorrect behaviour, present in the macOS for at least a year. Yet Apple has done nothing about it.

Comment: Started happening on my MacBook Pro 2015 after I upgraded to macOS Monterey 12.1. After locking my screen and logging in again, then I have to manually kill `bluetoothd`. I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: For me, my mac would start flying (fan noise) in the night and caught it red handed once. Checked the activity monitor and it was blutoothhd. I disabled the process and the fan slowed down. Researched a bit and found that CHORME used bluetooth.And chrome very rarely need Bluetooth. Its the laptop that connects to Bluetooth devices NOT CHROME. So disabled it and no issue anymore!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be quite a complex issue as Apple doesn't comment it/claims it doesn't happen: [macOS Catalina blueoothd high CPU IOBluetoothBroadcomSchedulerWorkaround issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377853/macos-catalina-blueoothd-high-cpu-iobluetoothbroadcomschedulerworkaround-issue?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still experiencing this issue, I have found a solution that worked in my case. I have described the detailed steps in reply to [another related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/409147/399602). Try to follow these steps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it wasn't due to the Monterrey upgrade.
I found a very simple solution:

Uncheck the **HP Smart.app** checkbox in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Bluetooth** and that's all!
I hope this will be useful for you.